# Is there any way to do servlet mapping in eclipse IDE other than manually?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

Recently,i have started to develop servlets using Eclipse.Every time i write a servlet program,i need to manually map them into web.xml.Is there any way to do automatic mapping of servlets??.Also the Eclipse asks for URL pattern whenever i create a new servlet file.Why is it asking when it doesnt maps into web.xml by itself??Note:also recommend any useful plugin for servlets/jsp development...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Upgrade to Servlet 3.0 (Apache Tomcat 7.0, Glassfish 3, etc), then all you need to do is to add the [`@WebServlet`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html) annotation to the servlet class.

```
@WebServlet("/foo")
public class FooServlet extends HttpServlet {
    // ...
}
```

That's it.

If you're still sticking to Servlet 2.5 or older, then you need to create the Servlet class as a Servlet class, not as a Java class. Rightclick project, choose *New > Servlet* and complete the wizard. This way Eclipse will just autogenerate the necessary `web.xml` mapping.

[image]

Comment: Really very helpful answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: How do I know if I upgraded to Servlet 3.0? Where can I do this? If I add the Annotation, I can not start my Tomcat Server

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use web.xml for servlet mapping then you need to select dynamic web facet 2.5 version instead of 3.0 in dynamic web project

Comment: thanks for this useful remark. This finally solved my problem!